# What do raw.githubusercontent.com URLs represent?

Tags: github, homebrew

I want to learn how to use [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/) to serve other applications from `github.com`.
So we have a usual way to download and install `homebrew` on osx.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I can't find the `install` file on GitHub. Where is it?

Comment: Are you asking us to explain how that install command works? Have you looked at the contents of the file referenced on `raw.githubusercontent.com`? Have you looked at the documentation for `curl`? Do you know what `$()` does in the shell? Do you know what `ruby -e` does?

Comment: I can't find 'install' file in repository, that's i asked this quitstion

Comment: Please note that rawgit.com is _not_ an alias for raw.githubusercontent.com. It is a third party service not affiliated to GitHub.

Comment: Also RawGit is at or near end-of-life; see https://rawgit.com/

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The `raw.githubusercontent.com` domain is used to serve unprocessed versions of files stored in GitHub repositories. If you browse to a file on GitHub and then click the **Raw** link, that's where you'll go.

The URL in your question references the [`install` file in the `master` branch](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/master/install) of the [`Homebrew/install` repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/install). The rest of that command just retrieves the file and runs `ruby` on its contents.

Comment: My assumption was that install script locates in main repository, thanks

Comment: What does "unprocessed versions of files" mean pls ?

Comment: @Tristan, it means you'll see the contents of the file without any GitHub UI, and files that typically get rendered (e.g. Markdown) won't be. You just see the raw text content of the file.

Comment: If I use GitHub public repo to store JSON files and be read from other places. **Should I use `raw.githubusercontent` or `GitHub pages` ?** I'm currently using `GitHub pages` link, it is shorter. But in case of re-upload I sometimes needed to wait a bit for `GitHub pages` to re-update itself. So **what people usually do?**

Comment: @zummon, that depends entirely on your use case and is pretty opinion-based. But if the _only_ reason for that repository is to host JSON files that get consumed elsewhere, I wouldn't personally set up a Pages site. Not sure why the length of the URL makes any difference.

Answer (score 55):

There are two ways of looking at github content, the "raw" way and the "Web page" way.

`raw.githubusercontent.com` returns the raw content of files stored in github, so they can be downloaded simply to your computer. For example, if the page represents a ruby install script, then you will get a ruby install script that your ruby installation will understand.

If you instead download the file using the github.com link, you will actually be downloading a web page with buttons and comments and which displays your wanted script in the middle -- it's what you want to give to your web browser to get a nice page to look at, but for the computer, it is not a script that can be executed or code that can be compiled, but a web page to be displayed. That web page has a button called **Raw** that sends you to the corresponding content on `raw.githubusercontent.com`.

To see the content of `raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/${branch}/${path}` in the usual github interface:

1. you replace `raw.githubusercontent.com` with plain `github.com`
2. **AND** you insert "blob" between the repo name and the branch name.

In this case, the user is "Homebrew", the repo is "install", the branch name is "master" (which is a very common branch name). You  insert "blob" between "install" and "master", so

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install
```

becomes

```
https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/master/install
```

This is the reverse of finding a file on Github and clicking the **Raw** link.

Comment: What does an argument to the URL mean, e.g. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<repo>/master/filters/file.txt?_=215612` - what is the `?_=215612`'s purpose

Comment: The `?` is simply to separate the "path" from the "searchpart" (RFC 1738 section 3.3). The searchpart is here `_=215612`. The searchpart does not have to be a search, it is interpreted by the server. What that could mean in a raw file I do not know. My only idea was that it could start or stop the data at that point in the file, but a test shows no difference. In fact, even on a normal github.com page I see no evidence of interpretation of the searchpart by github. If you still want to know, ask a new question, here or maybe on a forum dedicated to github.

Comment: It probably prevents client-side caching (because the content of files can change)

Comment: Not quite correct, you forgot the `user`, which comes first after the `hostname`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56943840/1705829) answer to learn about the user

Comment: @Timo True, I was conflating User and Repo, which might have been confusing. Improved, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

```
raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo-name/branch-name/path
```

Replace `username` with the username of the user that created the repo.

Replace `repo-name` with the name of the repo.

Replace `branch-name` with the name of the branch.

Replace `path` with the path to the file.

To reverse to go to GitHub.com:

```
GitHub.com/username/repo-name/directory-path/blob/branch-name/filename
```