# Github network unreachable

Tags: github, putty, socks

```
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com 
(raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.56.133|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

That's the error message, I'm trying to install Shadowsocks 443 via a script. I can access the page in browser just fine. Any ideas how to resolve? (Putty on Windows)

On my home network, so shouldn't have any issues. Also tried multiple networks to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If [`raw.githubusercontent.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39065921/6309) is somehow unreachable, try first to clone the repo (by script), and then call the installation script from the local clone.

That might be longer, but safer than trying to access directly the installation script.

---

But if the clone itself is not working, then it is probably more a local network issue, rather than anything else.
Possibly a proxy issue.

Comment: It appears that even git clone has issues connecting; in fact, ping google.com seems to be not working either

Comment: @AndrewWang OK, so you need to solve that network issue first, before trying anything GitHub-related.