# Can I access a Private Repository RAW file using a https call on Github?

Tags: github

I am trying to call the contents of a PS1, as raw, in Powershell out of Github. In GitLab this is doable by calling the following:

```
https://gitlab.com/USER/PRIVATEREPOS/raw/master/FileShares/SCRIPT.ps1?private_token=TOKENHERE
```

I am hoping there is a similar way to do this with GitHub - I've tried numerous things but none have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a similar URL, but using:

- [`raw.githubusercontent.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39065921/6309)
- a header [like `Authorization: token INSERTACCESSTOKENHERE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22314262/6309)

That should serve the raw content of that ps1 script.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by getting to the same resources via a different url - raw.githubusercontent.com (*hosted by github not a third-party*). If it is a private repository, you'll need:

- a personal access token referenced in the header of the request
- the project path on github
- the name of the script you're trying to get

To jump straight to the PowerShell code needed, it would be-

```
$baseurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yourproject/subdir/master"
$tokenheaders = @{"Authorization"="token tokenyougeneratedforprivateprojectaccess";"Accept"= "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"}
$scripturl="$baseurl/yourscript.ps1"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scripturl -Headers $tokenheaders -UseBasicParsing |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
```

This will get you the raw code, not a file, and this is using the deprecated v3 of the api, not v4 (*but is still working for me as of this writing and should for at least a few more years*).