# url of json file in reading pandas didn't work

Tags: json, pandas, json-normalize

I want to read json file using URL in pandas but it throws me some error, I think this is a relevant path I have given, Please look at the code and url. I didn't find it on stack overflow so asked it. This one may be duplicate but Please help me guys.

```
data_df = pd.read_json('https://github.com/jackiekazil/data-wrangling/blob/master/data/chp3/data-text.json')
```

json_url is below:

> https://github.com/jackiekazil/data-wrangling/blob/master/data/chp3/data-text.json

The error message:

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this URL: [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackiekazil/data-wrangling/master/data/chp3/data-text.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackiekazil/data-wrangling/master/data/chp3/data-text.json).

`raw.githubusercontent.com` serves the unprocessed files found in Github repositories.  The link that you posted in your question won't get you the raw JSON file you are interested in; instead, it loads the webpage itself.  It's also addressed in [`this answer.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39066549/3195451)

With the above URL, your code worked fine for me.

Comment: @ Daniel, could you please tell me why this shows me the parsing error with csv, same data as I mentioned above.  [ https://github.com/jackiekazil/data-wrangling/blob/master/data/chp3/data-text.csv ]

Answer (score 1):

- You won't be able to read the file directly with pandas
- You will need to download it

  - Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

    - *This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems.*
    - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
  - [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
- Incidentally, the function below will work for downloading any file from the correct URL.

  - The function requires the URL and the directory to save to.

```
import request
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def create_dir_save_file(dir_path: Path, url: str):
    """
    Check if the path exists and create it if it does not.
    Check if the file exists and download it if it does not.
    """
    if not dir_path.parents[0].exists():  # if directory doesn't exist
        dir_path.parents[0].mkdir(parents=True)  # create directory
        print(f'Directory Created: {dir_path.parents[0]}')
    else:
        print('Directory Exists')
        
    if not dir_path.exists():  # if file doesn't exist
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)  # get file
        open(dir_path, 'wb').write(r.content)  # write file
        print(f'File Created: {dir_path.name}')
    else:
        print('File Exists')
        

data_dir = Path.cwd()  # current working dir or use Path('e:/some_path') to specify a location
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackiekazil/data-wrangling/master/data/chp3/data-text.json'
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
data_path = data_dir / file_name  # local path to data once downloaded
create_dir_save_file(data_path, url)  # call function to download file

df = pd.json_normalize(data_path)  create dataframe

# display(df.head())

                           Indicator PUBLISH STATES  Year             WHO region World Bank income group               Country         Sex  Display Value  Numeric Low High Comments
0   Life expectancy at birth (years)      Published  1990                 Europe             High-income               Andorra  Both sexes             77     77.0                  
1   Life expectancy at birth (years)      Published  2000                 Europe             High-income               Andorra  Both sexes             80     80.0                  
2  Life expectancy at age 60 (years)      Published  2012                 Europe             High-income               Andorra      Female             28     28.0                  
3  Life expectancy at age 60 (years)      Published  2000                 Europe             High-income               Andorra  Both sexes             23     23.0                  
4   Life expectancy at birth (years)      Published  2012  Eastern Mediterranean             High-income  United Arab Emirates      Female             78     78.0
```