# Do all GitHub repositories follow the same URL structure?

Tags: github, github-api

Do all GitHub repositories have a URL path of the form `https://github.com/<OWNER>/<REPO>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes. But only if you are talking about navigating on github's website. Using github's api is a slightly different story and url.

When you need to pull down a particular file using github api, you have to use the github RAW urls. Heres another post that gives more context [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065921/what-do-raw-githubusercontent-com-urls-represent)