# How to make viewer like raw github

Tags: html, github

I need create a file viewer in html, because html can open only txt. Thing like I need - raw githubusercontent. How it works?

Comment: You will need to be more specific about what type of files you are using, how exactly you want them to appear, and what server-side language(s) are available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file viewer can use `curl`, you can use [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) to get the content URL of a file, and download it, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452512/6309):

```
API_URL=https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contents/path/file.ext
curl $(gh api $API_URL --jq .download_url) -o file.ext
```

That would simulate what [`raw.githubusercontent.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50703930/6309) does.
And not just for `.txt` files.