# GitHub API - "Get contents" continually returning 404 for valid path

Tags: node.js, github-api, node-request, probot

I'm using probot => https://probot.github.io/

I've been developing a GitHub application that analyses a specific `.json` file in a repo for changes to date strings.
I do this by subscribing to the `push` event and watching it with a `webhook`.

I am using `request` in Node. The issue I am having is that I continually receive a `404` when the hook runs. My code looks like this:

```
app.on('push', async context => {
    let repoOwner = context.payload.repository.owner.name;
    let repoName = context.payload.repository.name;

    const options = {
      url: `https://api.github.com/repos/${repoOwner}/${repoName}/contents/file.json`,
      headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
    }
    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      console.log(body) // logs {message: 'Not Found', documentation_url:... etc
      })
  })
```

<sub>previously I was not including a `user-agent` header which was constantly returning a `403` - GitHub's api specifies that you must pass a header. After doing this I am now constantly getting this `404`</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible reasons for a 404:

- the repository is private and you don't have access (that would require a header `"Authorization: token $TOKEN"`)
- The JSON response (since [the default answer is a JSON with the file contents encoded in base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14716043/6309)) exceed 1MB. The [Get Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) does mention "This API supports files up to 1 megabyte in size."
  Using a header "`Accept: application/vnd.github.3.raw`" would give you the raw content.

Comment: Do GitHub apps have a specific auth token? Or would I need to send the current user's auth token?

Comment: The user token or your own should be enough.

Comment: It is a private repo for sure, the app is installed on that repo. I want the app to be able to be authenticated to preform the 
`get content` call. However I can't figure out how to get the app's auth token.

I should note that I am using probot.

Comment: Any Pat (personal Access Token) of any collaborator having access to the private repository would do.