# Is there any way to fetch images using github's API?

Tags: javascript, github-api, fetch-api

I am fetching github's api to display my projects. I got titles, descriptions, links but I do not know if there is possibility to get an image from readme.md or from other place? I need it to display next to titles and descriptions. In github repo I have it in dir src/images/image_1 etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240961/github-jsonp-source-code-api for fetching specific files from git API

Comment: What do you mean by "get an image from readme.md or from other place"? readme.md is a text file.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents describes how to get a file from your repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Hellow brow, the way is

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UserName/NameRepo/Branch/NameImg.png`

The `UserName` is the name of the owner of the repository, `NameRepo` is the name of the repository, `Branch` is the branch of git, there may be several, but the default is `master`, `NameImg` is the name of the image and must also be with the expansion.